# Harvested prey–predator model incorporating a prey refuge

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, ecology

I want to plot the [phase diagram](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042705000488/1-s2.0-S0377042705000488-main.pdf?_tid=5fdd8afe-f5ec-11e6-ba56-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1487430805_0df6d62bf7f638a9869a74154aff1f52) of prey predator versus prey refuge to see how the prey refuge influences the population of prey and predator. And this is the system

$x'=\alpha x(1-x/k)-\beta\frac{(1-m)xy}{1+a(1-m)x}-q_1E_1x$

$y'=-\gamma y+c\beta\frac{(1-m)xy}{1+a(1-m)x}-q_2E_2y$

The prey predator with Holling type II model is incorporating a prey refuge, $mx$ and $k$, $\alpha$, $\gamma$, $c$ and $\beta/\alpha$ are the carrying capacity, growth rate of prey, death rate of predator, conversion factor denoting the number of newly born predators for each captured prey and maximum number of prey that can be eaten by each predator in unit time respectively.

I have the numerical value for $a=0.02$, $k=100$, $\alpha=10$, $\beta=0.6$, $\gamma=0.09$, $c=0.02$.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I see few demos here on this subject http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=predator%20prey

Comment: An article about this system can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705000488).

Comment: I think `NDSolve` is the function you are looking for.

Comment: A posts with 1000s of constants must miss a few ;-) Your m??

Answer (score 10):

I solved more general [**system linked**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705000488) by @SjoerdC.deVries in the comments reproducing figure 3 and 4 - to prove it is correct. You can simplify this to version you need.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

al = 2;
a = 2/1000;
k = 600;
b = 1/10;
g = 46/10^5;
c = 1/100;
m = 1/100;
E1 = 1;
q1 = 2/10;
E2 = 813/1000;
q2 = 2/100;
Tf = 300;

eqs = {
   x'[t] == 
    al x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - b (1 - m) x[t] y[t]/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]) - 
     q1 E1 x[t],
   y'[t] == -g y[t] + c b (1 - m) x[t] y[t]/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]) - 
     q2 E2 y[t],
   x[0] == 2, y[0] == 8};

s = NDSolve[eqs, {x, y}, {t, Tf}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, Tf}, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, Tf}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: interesting, your default plot colors are not the v9 defaults...  :)

Comment: Are these V 10 plots? They look different from V9 screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s7oLT.png) The lines are thicker also.

Comment: Well "it is not V9" says it all ;-) You can actually get same thing now on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3):

Some modifications for the code in Vitaliy Kaurov's answer:

```
<<MaTeX`
<< c:\CurvesGraphics6\CurvesGraphics6.m
```

Initial condition outside the limit cycle:

```
α = 200/207; 
a = 4; 
k = 3; 
β = 200/69 + 1/50; 
m = 1/2; 
c = 4761/20000; 
γ = 1/10; 
E1 = 500/621; 
q1 = 2/10; 
E2 = 3/4; 
q2 = 2/100; 
Tf = 1000; 
eqs1 = {x'[t] == -E1 q1 x[t] + x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) α - ((1 - m) x[t]*y[t] β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]), 
y'[t] == -E2 q2 y[t] + (c (1 - m) x[t]*y[t] β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]) - y[t]γ, x[0] == 1.1, y[0] == 1.1};
s1 = NDSolve[eqs1, {x, y}, {t, Tf}];

ts1 = Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[s1]], {t, 0, Tf}, 
PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.003]}, {Red, Thickness[0.003]}}, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> { MaTeX["\\text{t}", Magnification -> 1], 
MaTeX["\\text{Population densities}", Magnification -> 1]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], RotateLabel -> True, 
PlotPoints -> 500, ImageSize -> {300, 200}, 
DisplayFunction -> Identity]

pp1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s1], {t, 0, 100}, 
Axes -> False, Oriented -> True, ArrowPositions -> {0.05, 0.985}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.002], Arrowheads[0.035]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
RotateLabel -> True, 
FrameLabel -> { 
MaTeX["\\text{Prey population density}", Magnification -> 1], 
MaTeX["\\text{Predator population density}", Magnification -> 1]},
RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], 
ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image]

Initial condition inside the limit cycle:

```
α = 200/207; 
a = 4; 
k = 3; 
β = 200/69 + 1/50; 
m = 1/2; 
c = 4761/20000; 
γ = 1/10; 
E1 = 500/621; 
q1 = 2/10; 
E2 = 3/4; 
q2 = 2/100; 
Tf = 1000;
eqs2 = {x'[t] == -E1 q1 x[t] + x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) α - ((1 - m) x[t]*y[t] β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]), 
y'[t] == -E2 q2 y[t] + (c (1 - m) x[t]*y[t] β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x[t]) - y[t]γ, x[0] == 1.02, y[0] == 1.02};
s2 = NDSolve[eqs2, {x, y}, {t, Tf}];

ts2 = Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[s2]], {t, 0, Tf}, 
PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.003]}, {Red, Thickness[0.003]}}, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> { MaTeX["\\text{t}", Magnification -> 1], 
MaTeX["\\text{Population densities}", Magnification -> 1]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], RotateLabel -> True, 
PlotPoints -> 500, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
DisplayFunction -> Identity]

pp2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s2], {t, 900, Tf}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.008]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> True, 
FrameLabel -> { 
MaTeX["\\text{Prey population density}", Magnification -> 1], 
MaTeX["\\text{Predator population density}", Magnification -> 1]},
RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], 
ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image]

The initial conditions and equilibrium point:

```
p0 = Part[{x, y} /. NSolve[{-E1 q1 x + x (1 - x/k) α - ((1 - m) x*y β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x), -E2 q2 y + (c (1 - m) x*y β)/(1 + a (1 - m) x) - y γ} == {0, 0} && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}], 1];
(*{0.97972, 0.992966}*)
IC1 = {1.02, 1.02};
IC2 = {1.1, 1.1};

pointIC1 = 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Darker[Green], Point[IC1]}, 
IC1 - {-0.08, -0.011}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
ImageSize -> {250, 250}];

pointIC2 = 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Darker[Green], Point[IC2]}, 
IC2 - {-0.08, -0.011}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
ImageSize -> {250, 250}];
```

Finally, when applying the command **Show** produces

```
Show[pp2, pp21, pp1, pointIC1, pointIC2, 
Epilog -> {{PointSize[0.018], Black, Point[p0]}, {PointSize[0.013], 
White, Point[p0]}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> {350, 350}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code in `InputForm` if you want to contribute anything with code.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: This looks like it would be a valuable contribution if it were posted properly. Please read the instructions on formatting code given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584)

Comment: Thanks for your support M. Goldberg.