# Rosenzweig-MacArthur predator-prey model

Tags: differential-equations, ecology

The predator-prey model is governed by the following system of ode's.
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=r x\left(1 - \frac{x}{K}\right) - \frac{s y x}{1 + s \tau x}},\\[0.1cm]
&&\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dt}=-c y +d \frac{s x y}{1 + s \tau x}},
\end{eqnarray}
where $r,K,c,d>0$, $s$ is the  predator search rate and $\tau$ is time. The background of this model can be found [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~halsmith/Rosenzweig.pdf).

Using appropriate scaling as discussed [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~halsmith/Rosenzweig.pdf), the above the system can be written in the dimensionless form,

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=x\left(1 - \frac{x}{k}\right) - \frac{m y x}{1 + x}},\\[0.1cm]
&&\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dt}=-c y + \frac{m x y}{1 + x}}.
\end{eqnarray}

How to get solution of the above system?

How one can get phase portrait of the system?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the second equation should begin with $dy(x)/dt$ ?

Comment: Please write the equations in Mathematica syntax as well, and show what you tried. I assume you tried at least `DSolve`, and that if it couldn't solve it, you tried a numerical solution using `NDSolve`.  What went wrong when you tried these?  Explain where the difficulty is.

Comment: yes, I am sorry, edited.

Comment: What is the origin of this model?

Comment: It is from an article 'Stability analysis of a prey–predator model
incorporating a prey refuge' by Tapan Kumar Kar.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan Wait I have seen this somewhere...

Comment: @SkSarifHassan Here it is http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45922/predator-prey-model-with-prey-refuge?rq=1

Comment: @MMM, Yes it is.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan It's almost the same but your question is a slight simple case of that one.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan This mean yours is without harvesting?

Comment: @MMM, Yes, indeed. I intend to work on a hypothetical (abstract) model where entire system variables are complex instead of reals. To start, I was looking at solution of Real system. What do you think about complex formulation of the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53856/discussion-between-sk-sarif-hassan-and-mmm).

Comment: Non-Mathematica comments here:  I see that you got this model from a published paper, but I don't agree with how the "prey refuge" is incorporated here.  A refuge should leave a prey invulnerable to predation as long as they stay there; here it just decreases the effective predation rate.  In fact, this model is identical to the well-known Rosenzweig-MacArthur predator-prey model that combines logistic growth of prey and a type-II functional response.  A better model of a prey refuge would have two equations for prey (those in the refuge and those outside) and movement between them.

Comment: That said, if you want to change from a system with real variables to one with complex variables, you are probably not too interested in getting the biological details right ;)

Comment: @ChrisK, Yes, I wish to move to complex variable to get insight of the abstract model from mathematical interest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Note**

In my attempt to answer the OP's question, I have presented all most all the visuals/graphs which are important for the analysis of such models. If there is something missing or physically incorrect then please feel free to edit and correct?

Credit goes to @ChrisK for pointing me in the right direction, which made me able to carry out correct graphical analysis of the model.

The equations and values for the different parameters are take from the document cited in the question.

**Solution & Plot**

To solve such nonlinear systems, the best choice, in almost all cases is to use `NDSolve` to get numerical solutions.

```
c = 1; m = 3;
sol = With[{k = 3}, First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - m*x[t]*y[t]/(1 + x[t]), 
     y'[t] == m*x[t]*y[t]/(1 + x[t]) - c*y[t], x[0] == 1, 
     y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}]]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 50}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, Frame -> True,
PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Directive[Green, Dashed]}, {"prey", "predator"}]]
```

[image]

**Nullclines**

```
nk1 = With[{k = 3}, ContourPlot[{((1 - x/k) - m*y/(1 + x)), (m*x/(1 + x) - c), 
     y}, {x, -1.5, 3.5}, {y, -0.5, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["k>(m+c)/(m-c)", 12], Scaled[{0.7, 0.9}]]}]];

nk2 = With[{k = 1}, ContourPlot[{((1 - x/k) - m*y/(1 + x)), (m*x/(1 + x) - c), 
     y}, {x, -1.5, 3.5}, {y, -0.5, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["k<(m+c)/(m-c)", 12], Scaled[{0.7, 0.9}]]}]];

GraphicsGrid[{{nk1, nk2}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Phase Portrait**

```
sol1[k_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := 
  First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - m*x[t]*y[t]/(1 + x[t]), 
     y'[t] == m*x[t]*y[t]/(1 + x[t]) - c*y[t], x[0] == x0, 
     y[0] == x0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}];

ppk1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol1[1, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]], {t, 0, 
    200}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["k=1", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 1.6}}];

ppk3 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol1[3, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]], {t, 0, 
    200}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["k=3", 20], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 1.6}}];

GraphicsGrid[{{ppk1, ppk3}}]
```

[image]

```
sp1 = With[{k = 1}, 
   StreamPlot[{x*(1 - x/k) - m*x*y/(1 + x), m*x*y/(1 + x) - c*y}, {x, 
     0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}]];

sp2 = With[{k = 3}, 
   StreamPlot[{x*(1 - x/k) - m*x*y/(1 + x), m*x*y/(1 + x) - c*y}, {x, 
     0, 2.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}]];

GraphicsGrid[{{Show[ppk1, sp1, nk2], Show[ppk3, sp2, nk1]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice start.  For more interesting results, you should increase `c` relative to `d` (otherwise the predators can't persist no matter how much prey they have) and then use prey carrying capacity `k` as a bifurcation parameter.  This is the well-known Rosenzweig-MacArthur predator-prey model.  As you increase `k` there is a Hopf bifurcation where a predatory-prey limit cycle is born.

Comment: @MMM, how to achieve the bifurcation diagram of the model with respect to the parameter k?

Comment: @SkSarifHassan Check my edited response.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan Is this what you wanted? or I am missing something?

Comment: @MMM, yes it is. I was thinking from complex variable point of view. What about bifurcation diagram for k?

Comment: I did not see last plot. Yes! Sorry. Will solution be bounded if we start from unit ball in complex plane, what do you think?

Comment: @SkSarifHassan I don't know. If it is about *Mathematica* then ask about it as a new question?